# Error in downloading PDF file from ABL Code

Tags: sockets, pdf, progress-4gl, openedge

When I run a test with the routine indicated by Progress to download a PDF file, I have the following problem. Some files download correctly, others bring only one part, and therefore the file is invalid.

I did the test with 2 random links, where one of them is correct, and the other one has an error.

Has anyone ever come across this situation?

Reference: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-download-PDF-files-from-ABL-code

Thanks!

My Code:

```
/* http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-download-PDF-files-from-ABL-code   */
/* Article Number   000080110                                                                   */

USING OpenEdge.Core.*. 
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.*. 
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.Lib.ClientLibraryBuilder. 

DEFINE VARIABLE oRequest AS IHttpRequest NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE VARIABLE oResponse AS IHttpResponse NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE VARIABLE oRequestBody AS WidgetHandle NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE VARIABLE oResponseMemptrEntity AS OpenEdge.Core.Memptr NO-UNDO. 
DEFINE VARIABLE oByteBucket AS OpenEdge.Core.ByteBucket NO-UNDO. 


/*IT'S OK*/
oRequest = RequestBuilder:GET ("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"):Request. 
oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute(oRequest). 

oByteBucket = CAST(oResponse:Entity,OpenEdge.Core.ByteBucket). 
oResponseMemptrEntity = oByteBucket:GetBytes(). 

COPY-LOB FROM oResponseMemptrEntity:Value TO FILE "c:\temp\FILE-OK.pdf".



/*IT'S ERROR*/
oRequest = RequestBuilder:GET ("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf"):Request. 
oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute(oRequest). 

oByteBucket = CAST(oResponse:Entity,OpenEdge.Core.ByteBucket). 
oResponseMemptrEntity = oByteBucket:GetBytes(). 

COPY-LOB FROM oResponseMemptrEntity:Value TO FILE "c:\temp\FILE-ERROR.pdf".
```

Comment: You say that you get an error.  What is that error?

Comment: Which OpenEdge Release and Service Pack?

Comment: @MikeFechner Release 11.6

Comment: @TomBascom Thanks for the answer.

It does not save the file completely.

It writes the initial content of the file and quits without displaying any error.

So with the incomplete file, the error occurs while opening the file.

Comment: For me it actually works. Windows 10. Openedge 11.6.(32 bit installation).

Comment: If you enable logging, are there any interesting errors or messages? Used the LOG-MANAGER ; set a log file and use a LOGGING-LEVEL of 5.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your sample code on OpenEdge 11.7 (64 bit) and it seems to download both files with no issues.

The OpenEdge.net.pl has been updated throughout the OpenEdge 11.6 service packs. 11.6.3 is the most recent one. I would suggest you try to upgrade to 11.6.3 (service pack 3 of OpenEdge 11.6) and try again.

Comment: Thank you! I will run the tests with 11.6.3.

Comment: After an update of the Package, the program behaved correctly. Thanks for the tip!  Thanks!!!!!